# Lacking the knowledge and skills

Tags: management, startup

I am working in a tech start up, we are building a product and it has got to the point where we need to scale our servers so that it can handle huge traffic. The problem is that we have nobody here that has knowledge of dev ops, this is problematic since we have some high profile clients interested in working with us on the condition that we can handle a large load.

Anyway - my boss's attitude is for us to self teach ourselves dev ops, and is expecting us to handle the load on a single server. My attitude is that we need to hire somebody in that is a specialist and invest money on more servers. I am in a bit of a tight spot in the sense that we do not have the money to get new people in and build our server architecture, but I just don't know how to break this to my boss?

My boss is the type of guy who believe's nothing is impossible, and we can find the answers through googling. My concern is that he is underestimating the complexity of the task, and if we needed to expand the servers, we don't have the capital otherwise I would suggest we put the platform onto Amazon or Google app engine.

Comment: Is it a negative thing to say to your boss? i.e. not taking initiative or willing to learn more?

Comment: If your boss believes that 'nothing is impossible', ask him to find the money to expand onto AWS. After all, 'nothing is impossible'....

Comment: You don't have a way to simulate a load and test?

Comment: Yes, using jmeter, the problem is knowing what to do after you find out the server is slow

Comment: Microsoft has a program, specifically to support startups: https://bizspark.microsoft.com//#start-one In general, cloud services including AWS (#1 in market share), Microsoft (#2 in market share) and Google Development Platform (GDP) are cheaper than the TCO of buying your own hardware, dedicating a server room for your servers, wiring your servers, etc. Most learn Devops the hard way, by the way. You can familiarize yourself with Devops wrt Software Engineering by experimenting with circleci.com, codeship.com  or travis-ci.org If you want to experiment with Jenkins, try cloudbees.com

Comment: Microsoft Azure, of course, has its own support for Devops. If you don't know anything about Jenkins, don't screw around with Jenkins unless you are a sucker for punishment and you are into pain :). You design and implement your Devops pipelines by trial-and-error - mostly error :)

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much! I am pushing to move onto a cloud platform - AWS comes to mind. The issue is cost really, if we get a million requests how much will it be, I'm aware it's all pay as you go - so hard to estimate. Also for a complete noob at Dev ops, if we moved to these platforms will we be able to install our own stuff onto it? I used azure once and it looked like you couldn't unless you bought a dedicated instance, which doesn't scale. Finally when scaling happens will performance stay the same?

Comment: You cant afford a new employee but can you afford to bring in a consultant for a month specifically to look at  your program and make recommendations (and hopefully you can learn from while they are there)?

Comment: @JasonJ can't afford that either ironically. Consultant is going to cost £300- 600 a day.

Comment: It can cost much more going wrong, either business failure or some taking the fall. Also from my experience, putting developer people doing full sysadmin jobs, especially like the one you are describing is not the brightest of the ideas.Consultants exist for a reason.

Comment: Just talked my boss into bringing a consultant in. I told him that the developer time is better spent on developing new features not doing dev ops.

Answer (score 4):

## Get a Consultant In

That's what they're there for, to give you the maximum amount of value in a defined period of time.

It'll be far more valuable to have someone who knows the technology than it will to attempt to ramp yourself up (and then get bitten when/if) it all goes wrong.

Comment: Make sure the consultant's assigned task is to bring the dept. up to speed on these skills, not just to set up the environment, and select someone who has teaching as well as tech skills. We did exactly this when I bootstrapped from C to Java (though I had prior exposure to OO design concepts.)

Answer (score 1):

I would fall back on metrics. 
Estimate the work, and likewise the risk of failure and the impact on the business.

Then at least the boss and everyone is making a decision, on the basis of some information.

When you analyse the metrics, it often changes your perspective on a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Take advantage of free**

As a startup, there are programs with most major cloud providers that will give you up to a year with zero charge for substantial use of their services.

**The DevOps revolution is your friend**

Infrastructure as code has made much of this easier. I won't endorse particular tools here, but there are many in the open source community that do much of the heavy lifting, and will be familiar to developers.

**Tech Scaling is optimization**

Measure your components to find the bottlenecks that can give you at least a 10x performance improvement on that component. Then replace that component with something better. Repeat. Each time fix the very next thing blocking--you should see immediate benefit, or skip it.

**Don't forget business/process scaling**

If there's something not automated--maintenance, shipping on order, etc--that takes you 5 minutes today, and you have to do it 100x more often, it now take you 2.5 business weeks. This is often overlooked--your tech can quickly outstrip your ability to satisfy customers.

Many people have gone before you with fewer skills, and gotten very far. When you think you have to build something always ask yourself (a) who has built this before and made it available, or (b) why am I doing something different than everyone else? The largest scaled companies in the world--Google, Facebook, Netflix, and others--have made their tools and experience available for free.

Comment: While Amazon lets you *test* for a year the service, and this period is interesting to learn the tools/self-training, it wont support any real enterprise workload. It takes time, and a good working foundation to get familiar with the technologies. One thing it to throw to the air a lot of jargon, another is to get real work done in a short time frame. As other post suggest, I would hire a consultant.